# Null string not recognized as null or empty

Tags: android

I am getting a JSON string from a remote URL.

There is a value on the string called mediafile.

Sometimes this value is null.

I need to check if it is null to execute some functions, but with my code its value is never recognized as null:

```
Log.d("home_post","home_post: mediapostfile MEDIAFILE valor="+mediafile);

        if(mediafile!=null || !mediafile.isEmpty( ) {
// do something if it has a value
}
else {
// do something if null
}
```

And this the log to demonstrate that it can be null, and not recognized as null, then the else parte is never called:

```
D/home_post: home_post: mediapostfile MEDIAFILE valor=null
```

Comment: Are you sure the value is not `"null"`? That would explain your Logcat entry and your `if` condition failure -- `mediafile` would hold `"null"`, which is not `null` and not empty, yet your Logcat would show `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, you mean the string "null" ? May be, let me check.

Comment: @CommonsWare, that is. Not enough knowledge to take it into account.

Comment: This is expected to throw exception in case mediafile is null `mediafile!=null || !mediafile.isEmpty()` You can change it to `mediafile!=null && !mediafile.isEmpty()`

Comment: The string object with content "null" is not equal null